# How to set dynamic value in springboot for connecting to mysql?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kubernetes

Currently, I have this in my `springboot` `application.dev.yaml`:

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql/$DB_HOST?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I want to add a dynamic value in username, passwords, `$DB_HOST` field so that it can pick those values from the secrets file in `Kubernetes`.
The secrets file in `Kubernetes` is encrypted with base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot, any property can be overridden by an environment variable of the same name, with the characters changed to upper case, and the dots changed to underscores.

For example datasource.url can be overridden by setting an environment variable like DATASOURCE_URL, which you define in Kubernetes

Source: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/04/configuring-spring-boot-kubernetes-secrets#setup

Comment: Okay, I have been going through the article and it's exactly what I want to use but I have `application.yaml` and `application.dev.yaml` there's no `application.properties`. Are these the same? Also, can I add the fragment part in the springboot-deployment.yml itself? Also, should I remove the datasource completely? or add this to it?

Comment: Yes, yaml and properties files work the same way. You can leave the values ​​as default to run the application outside of kubernetes

Comment: I added the `security.user.name` and the same for password and tried but I got this: ```I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL https://172.17.0.10:8778/jolokia/
10:19:41.492 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 32, column 1:
    security.user.name=${SECRETS_DEM ... 
    ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 33, column 1:
    security.user.password=${SECRETS ... 
    ^
```

Comment: okay, It works but now I have new issue, I have to now use the jkube plugin to build this